# I get an TypeError in python3 when I use Pandas and sep function

Tags: python, pandas

I try to manipulate a real big dataset in python using pandas. The code I am using is the following

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas import Series
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
df = pd.read_csv('Medicare.txt', 'r', sep='\t', na_values=['.'])
print (len(df))
df.head(10)
```

The error I am receiving is the following

```
TypeError: parser_f() got multiple values for argument 'sep'
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second positional argument to read_csv is `sep`. For some reason you are passing an 'r' there, as well as an explicit `sep` kwarg.

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much. I removed 'r' and everything went as expected. Except that I am getting a warning
`/home/antonis/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2717: DtypeWarning: Columns (10) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
  interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)`
Is there something to worry about?